# Calculating data from external source

Tags: jquery

In the following I am trying to obtain price1 and add to it the product of price2 x the number of weeks.

The prices appear correctly in their form text boxes (#hQuotePrice and #hTotalExtraWeek) but when I try to read these to make a calculation usinkg the variable price1 and price2 I get an error.

As a novice I am probably either doing it all wrong or missing something really simple.

```
var diffs = (getDayDiff(parseDate(FromDateValue), parseDate(ToDateValue)) - 31);
var weeks = (diffs / 7);

$.get('_getprice.asp?QuoteRef=' + (qrefval + qcodeval), function(data) {
    $('#hQuotePrice').val(data);
});

$.get('_getprice.asp?QuoteRef=' + (extraweekcode), function(data) {
    $('#hTotalExtraWeek').val(data*weeks);
});

var price1 = $('#hQuotePrice').val();
var price2 = $('#hTotalExtraWeek').val();

$("#TotalPrice").html("<strong>Total Price £</strong>: " + (price1 + price2));
```

Comment: What is the error? On first look I would suggest using `parseFloat` before doing math on the values.

Comment: Yes, it needed this too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that the two AJAX calls are asynchronous. This means that your logic is attempting to work with the returned values before the requests have completed. To fix this you need to perform the calculation after the AJAX returns the data, for which you can use `$.when()`, like this:

```
var diffs = (getDayDiff(parseDate(FromDateValue), parseDate(ToDateValue)) - 31);
var weeks = (diffs / 7);

$.when(
  $.get('_getprice.asp?QuoteRef=' + (qrefval+qcodeval), function(data) {
    $('#hQuotePrice').val(data);
  }),    
  $.get('_getprice.asp?QuoteRef=' + (extraweekcode), function(data) {
    $('#hTotalExtraWeek').val(data * weeks);
  })
).done(function() {
  var price1 = $('#hQuotePrice').val();
  var price2 = $('#hTotalExtraWeek').val();
  $("#TotalPrice").html("<strong>Total Price £</strong>: " + (price1 + price2));  
});
```